# A particular polynomial

Tags: polynomials

Is there a homogeoneous polynomial in $\Bbb Z[W,X,Y,X]$ that contains only coefficients (which may be $0$) from $W^4,X^4,Y^4,Z^4,W^2X^2,W^2Y^2,X^2Z^2,Y^2Z^2,WXYZ$ that factorizes into unequal quadratic forms?

What is a polynomial with least such coefficients from the list (something that uses all variables at least in the degree $4$ polynomial) with positive coefficients?

Comment: What if I just took any one of those monomials?

Comment: No. That is too trivial.

Comment: the monomials are not symmetric except WXYZ =(WX)(YZ). Which is i answer.The factors need not be symmetric. By homogeneous do you mean symmetric?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$W^2Y^2+2WXYZ+X^2Z^2=(WY+XZ)^2$$

**Added later** (after the OP's edit):

$$W^2X^2+W^2Y^2+X^2Z^2+Y^2Z^2=(W^2+Z^2)(X^2+Y^2)$$

is a factorization into unequal quadratics, using all four variables and positive coefficients.

Comment: is it symmetric?

Comment: @Turbo, what do you mean by symmetric?

Comment: symmetric with respect to permutation of variables? Like $A^2+2AB+B^2$?

Comment: Your list of monomials is missing $W^2Z^2$ and $X^2Y^2$, so I don't see how you can get anything that's symmetric with respect to *all* the permutations of the variables.

Comment: Ok thank you for the observation. I have corrected to mention I need unequal quadratic forms preferably with all coefficients positive.

Comment: thank you. you think you could get all nine variables?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1409799/a-particular-polynomial-2

Comment: I think it'll help if you clarify at the new question that you want a factorization into quadratics which, when expanded, includes *all* the monomials in your list.

Comment: Yes precisely. That is what I want.

Answer (score 0):

For the first question, $WXYZ= (WX)(YZ)$ .  Did I misunderstand something?

Comment: spam read through comment way above.