# A particular polynomial - 2

Tags: polynomials

Is there a homogeoneous polynomial in $\Bbb Z[W,X,Y,X]$ that contains only coefficients from $W^4,X^4,Y^4,Z^4,W^2X^2,W^2Y^2,X^2Z^2,Y^2Z^2,WXYZ$ that factorizes into unequal quadratic forms?

What is a polynomial with all such coefficients from the list (want a factorization into quadratics which, when expanded, includes all the monomials in your list) with positive coefficients?

Both quadratics should preferrably have similar number of coefficients.

Comment: Please explain how this differs from what you were initially asking at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1409674/a-particular-polynomial -- as it stands, it's almost an exact duplicate.

Comment: all coefficients.

Comment: Is there some reason not to have all six possible products of two squares in your list of factors to draw from? You've omitted $W^2Z^2$ and $X^2Y^2.$

Comment: That is the catch.

Comment: I believe your Readers would be more eager to help with this if you presented a more generous motivation for the changes.

Comment: there is really no motivation. I just am unable to find something along this.

Comment: SInce your list of allowable terms are each homogeneous of degree 4, no need to require that. So you're asking for two quadratics $p,q$ (all terms either squares or products of two vars) for which, when $pq$ is expanded, the result contains eacn monomial on your desired list with a positive coefficient, and no other monomials. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: And also the factor should also have positive coefficients.

Comment: Turbo: That's a lot to ask, maybe it can't be done. :( I found some not having all your tems...

Comment: can you post what you have?

Comment: Turbo: OK but one part is a negative result, and my other part gives one having all terms including the other two products of squares. Post soon...

Comment: @coffeemath thank you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27437/discussion-between-coffeemath-and-turbo).

Answer (score 1):

Let $P=\sum a_ix_i^2+\sum a_{i,j}x_ix_j$ and $Q$ similarly with $b_i$ and $b_{i,j}.$ Now provided you want all coefficients positive, and also want each of $x_i^4$ to appear in the product with positive coefficients, comparing coefficients shows each $a_i>0,$ and each $b_i>0.$ So from these terms alone there is already a positive contribution to each of the *six* cross-square terms, meaning products of two squares. If cross terms from $P$ i.e. $a_{i,j}x_ix_j$ are used and or cross terms from $Q$ are used, this won't kill off any of the six cross-square terms we already have, since the coefficients of the factors have been required to be positive or zero.

Now I *did* find an example in which we drop the positivity requirements for the coefficients of the factors and the result, but in the product all six products of two squares appear. This example is 
$$P=x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^3+x_4^2+x_1x_2+x_3x_4,\\
Q=x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^3+x_4^2-x_1x_2-x_3x_4.$$
I have not been able to find one with two of the products of two squares missing as your list implies.

*A better example*: Define $$P(a)=w^2+x^2+y^2+z^2+awz+axy.$$
Then $P(\sqrt{2})\cdot P(-\sqrt{2})$ has all and only nonzeo terms from your list.
$$w^4+x^4+y^4+z^4+2w^2x^2+2w^2y^2+2x^2z^2+2y^2z^2-4wxyz.$$
[There are still negative coefficients in one of the factors and in the product, but this cannot be completely avoided anyway as noted above.]

Comment: All six product of two squares appearing is easy I think.

Comment: @Turbo Just added an example fitting your list, only four nonzero products of two squares.

Comment: @Turbo I noticed your apparent restriction to integer coefficients. Maybe this could be done, but my example has an irrational coefficient in the factors.

Comment: thank you but there is negative term though/. Weird right may be need to be in $\Bbb Z[\mathsf{i}]$ coefficients?

Comment: @Turbo Did you notice that in the first paragraph is a proof it cannot be done with all positive terms? Also what is your view on terms with irrational coefficients? And by Z[I] coefficients do you mean coefficients in the Gaussian integers? If so since there is no order relation there it may be possible, since 2 has a squareroot in a sense namely $1+i$.